# How to make ribbon and eureka aware of a server not being up anymore

Tags: java, netflix-eureka, netflix, netflix-ribbon

I am working in an microservices architecture that works as follows

[image]

I have two service web applications (REST services) that register themselves correctly in an eureka server, then I have a client application that fetches the eureka registry and using ribbon as a client side load balancer, determines to which service application go (at the moment, a simple Round Robin is being used).

My problem is that when I stop one of the service applications (they currently run in docker containers btw), eureka does not remove them from their registry (seems to take a few minutes) so ribbon still thinks that there are 2 available services, making around 50% of the calls fail.

Unfortunately I am not using Spring Cloud (reasons out of my control). So my config for eureka is as follows.

For the service applications:

```
eureka.registration.enabled=true
eureka.name=skeleton-service
eureka.vipAddress=skeleton-service
eureka.statusPageUrlPath=/health/ping
eureka.healthCheckUrlPath=/health/check

eureka.port.enabled=8042
eureka.port=8042

eureka.appinfo.replicate.interval=5

## configuration related to reaching the eureka servers
eureka.preferSameZone=true
eureka.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://eureka-container:8080/eureka/v2/

eureka.decoderName=JacksonJson
```

For the client application (eureka + ribbon)

```
###Eureka Client configuration for Sample Eureka Client


eureka.registration.enabled=false 
eureka.name=skeleton-web
eureka.vipAddress=skeleton-web
eureka.statusPageUrlPath=/health/ping
eureka.healthCheckUrlPath=/health/check

eureka.port.enabled=8043
eureka.port=8043

## configuration related to reaching the eureka servers
eureka.preferSameZone=true
eureka.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.serviceUrl.default=http://eureka-container:8080/eureka/v2/

eureka.decoderName=JacksonJson

eureka.renewalThresholdUpdateIntervalMs=3000


#####################
# RIBBON STUFF HERE #
#####################

sample-client.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.niws.loadbalancer.DiscoveryEnabledNIWSServerList

# expressed in milliseconds
sample-client.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval=3000

# movieservice is the virtual address that the target server(s) uses to register with Eureka server
sample-client.ribbon.DeploymentContextBasedVipAddresses=skeleton-service
```

Comment: I think you should add eureka unregister step to your JVM shutdown hook manually

Comment: I suspect @SakuraKyouko is correct in that if you are killing one of your services, then eureka probably never gets your instance's deregistration call(https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations) and then has to wait until it fails renewal for 90s (defualt - https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-eureka-client-server-communication#renew). Out of curiosity, how many instances are you typically dealing with? I'm also wondering if self preservation mode may be a factor here.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue in my development ,
There are multiple things I tried and worked for me .

1)Instead of using eureka registry ,use only underlying ribbon and modify it's health check mechanism as per our need ,for doing this provide own implementation for IPing

```
public class PingUrl implements com.netflix.loadbalancer.IPing {

public boolean isAlive(Server server) {
        String urlStr = "";
        if (isSecure) {
            urlStr = "https://";
        } else {
            urlStr = "http://";
        }
        urlStr += server.getId();
        urlStr += getPingAppendString();

        boolean isAlive = false;
        try {
            ResponseEntity response = getRestTemplate().getForEntity(urlStr, String.class);
            isAlive = (response.getStatusCode().value()==200);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ;
        }
        return isAlive;
    }
}
```

override the load balancing behaviour

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@RibbonClients(defaultConfiguration = LoadBalancer.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test"})
public class APIGateway {   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(APIGateway .class, args);
    }
```

}

```
    public class LoadBalancer{

    @Autowired
        IClientConfig ribbonClientConfig;

    @Bean
        public IPing ribbonPing() {

            return new PingUrl(getRoute() + "/ping");
        }
    }

  private String getRoute() {
        return RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getServletPath();
}
```

providing availability filtering rule

```
public class AvailabilityBasedServerSelectionRule extends AvailabilityFilteringRule {

    @Override
    public Server choose(Object key) {

        Server chosenServer = super.choose(key);

        int count = 1;
        List<Server> reachableServers = this.getLoadBalancer().getReachableServers();
        List<Server> allServers = this.getLoadBalancer().getAllServers();

        if(reachableServers.size() > 0) {
            while(!reachableServers.contains(chosenServer) && count++ < allServers.size()) {
                chosenServer = reachableServers.get(0);
            }
        }
        return chosenServer;
    }
```

}
2)You can specify the time interval for refreshing the list

```
ribbon.eureka.ServerListRefreshInterval={time in ms}
```